# JSON sub array - PHP decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON feed and within the feed, there is an array inside the feed, I can output everything above the array correctly.

JSON feed output: http://pastebin.com/pxiFVm1d

Code used to output:

```
$jsonurl = "LINK to feed";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);

foreach ( $json_output->results as $results )
{
    echo "{$results->name}.<br />";
}
```

How do I output the `photo_rerence` which is part of the array (see pastebin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you make a "deep pick": `$results['photos']['photo_reference']`, or take a look at phps `array_walk()` function which allows you to "search" through the array in a recursive manner.

Answer (score 1):

If there's the possibility that there might be multiple photos you could do:

```
$json_output = json_decode($json);
foreach ( $json_output->results as $results )
{
    foreach($results->photos as $photo) {
        echo $photo->photo_reference;
    }
}
```

Or if you only ever want to grab from the first one in the array just do:

```
$json_output = json_decode($json);
foreach ( $json_output->results as $results )
{
   echo $results->photos[0]->photo_reference;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what arkascha said, if you want to use it as an array, you will need to add the second param on your json_decode:

```
$json_output = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

Refer to [php.net/json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) for details.